# FLUTTER: problem with fetching 'isFavorite' in HTTP

Tags: flutter, dart, null, boolean

I am learning flutter and working on a dummy shop app for backend learning purposes. In my Firebase realtime database, 'isFavorite' is getting set as 'true'. But after refreshing the screen, 'Icons.favorite' is getting set as 'Icons.favorite_border'. It should be shaded. Hence, 'Icons.favorite' is the correct icon for it since it is 'true' in Firebase. It's consuming me a lot of time but I want to fix it regardless.

dependencies(pubspec.yaml):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^6.0.5
  intl: ^0.18.0
  http: ^0.13.5
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/cart_screen.dart';
import './providers/cart.dart';
import './providers/product.dart';
import './screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './providers/products_provider.dart';
import '../providers/orders.dart';
import './screens/orders_screen.dart';
import './screens/user_product_screen.dart';
import './screens/edit_product_screen.dart';
import './screens/auth_screen.dart';
import './providers/auth.dart';

final MaterialColor primaryColor = MaterialColor(
  0xFFEBEDF3,
  <int, Color>{
    50: Color(0xFFF3F4F7),
    100: Color(0xFFE6E8EC),
    200: Color(0xFFD0D4DD),
    300: Color(0xFFB8BDC9),
    400: Color(0xFFA0A6B2),
    500: Color(0xFF878E9C),
    600: Color(0xFF767D8C),
    700: Color(0xFF636D7A),
    800: Color(0xFF505C68),
    900: Color(0xFF3D4A56),
  },
);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (ctx) => Auth(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductsProvider>(
            //update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => ProductsProvider(auth.token),
            create: (ctx) => ProductsProvider(
              '',
              '',
              [],
            ),
            update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => ProductsProvider(
                auth.token!,
                auth.userId,
                previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (ctx) => Cart(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
            //update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => ProductsProvider(auth.token),
            create: (ctx) => Orders('', []),
            update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(auth.token!,
                previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders),
          ),
        ],
        child: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: primaryColor)
                    .copyWith(
                  secondary: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
              ),
              home: auth.isAuth ? ProductsOverviewScreen() : AuthScreen(),
              routes: {
                ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
                CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
                OrdersScreen.routeName: (ctx) => OrdersScreen(),
                UserProductScreen.routeName: (ctx) => UserProductScreen(),
                EditProductScreen.routeName: (ctx) => EditProductScreen(),
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is my product_overview_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../widgets/app_drawer.dart';
import '../screens/cart_screen.dart';
import '../widgets/badge.dart';
import '../widgets/products_grid.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';
import '../providers/products_provider.dart';

enum FilterOptions {
  Favorites,
  All,
}

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProductsOverviewScreen> createState() => _ProductsOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {
  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  // @override
  void initState() {
    //
    // Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
    //   Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context).fetchAndSetProduct();
    // });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context).fetchAndSetProduct().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final productsData = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyShop'),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (FilterOptions selectedValue) {
              setState(() {
                if (selectedValue == FilterOptions.Favorites) {
                  _showOnlyFavorites = true;
                } else {
                  _showOnlyFavorites = false;
                }
              });
            },
            itemBuilder: (_) => const [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Only Favorites'),
                value: FilterOptions.Favorites,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Show All'),
                value: FilterOptions.All,
              ),
            ],
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.more_vert,
            ),
          ),
          Consumer<Cart>(
            builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
              child: ch as Widget,
              value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              key: UniqueKey(),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ProductsGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
    );
  }
}
```

My product_item.dart widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';
import '../providers/auth.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String id;
  // final String title;
  // final String imageUrl;

  // ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    final authData = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoriteStatus(authData.token!, authData.userId);
              },
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              cart.addItem(
                  product.id, product.title, product.quantity, product.price);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: const Text(
                  'Added Item',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Undo',
                  onPressed: () {
                    cart.removeSingleItem(product.id);
                  },
                ),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Product model

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
    isFavorite = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int? get quantity => null;

  Future<void> toggleFavoriteStatus(String? token, String userId) async {
    final oldStatus = isFavorite;
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;

    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId/$id.json?auth=$token');
    try {
      final response = await http.put(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'isFavorite': isFavorite,
          }));
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        _setFavValue(oldStatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _setFavValue(oldStatus);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isFavoriteState {
    return isFavorite;
  }
}
```

And lastly, my products_provider.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shop_app/models/http_exeception.dart';

import './product.dart';

class ProductsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    // Product(
    //   id: 'p1',
    //   title: 'Red Shirt',
    //   description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
    //   price: 29.99,
    //   imageUrl:
    //       'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    // ),
    // Product(
    //   id: 'p2',
    //   title: 'Trousers',
    //   description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
    //   price: 59.99,
    //   imageUrl:
    //       'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    // ),
    // Product(
    //   id: 'p3',
    //   title: 'Yellow Scarf',
    //   description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
    //   price: 19.99,
    //   imageUrl:
    //       'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    // ),
    // Product(
    //   id: 'p4',
    //   title: 'A Pan',
    //   description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
    //   price: 49.99,
    //   imageUrl:
    //       'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    // ),
  ];

  // var _showFavoritesOnly = false;

  final String authToken;
  final String userId;

  ProductsProvider(this.authToken, this.userId, this._items);

  List<Product> get items {
    // if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
    //   return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
    // }
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }

  Future<void> fetchAndSetProduct() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url = Uri.parse(
          'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken');
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'] ?? '',
          description: prodData['description'] ?? '',
          price: prodData['price'] ?? 0.0,
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'] ?? '',
          isFavorite: favoriteData == null
              ? false
              : (favoriteData[prodId] ?? false) is bool
                  ? favoriteData[prodId]
                  : false,
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken');
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
          'price': product.price,
        }),
      );
      final newProduct = Product(
          id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
          price: product.price);
      // _items.add(value);
      _items.add(newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) async {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
      await http.patch(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'title': newProduct.title,
          'description': newProduct.description,
          'price': newProduct.price,
          'imageUrl': newProduct.imageUrl,
        }),
      );
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(String id) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/$id.json?auth=$authToken');
    final existingProductIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    Product? existingProduct = _items[existingProductIndex];

    _items.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
    notifyListeners();
    final response = await http.delete(url);
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      _items.insert(existingProductIndex, existingProduct);
      notifyListeners();
      throw HttpException('Could not delete product.');
    }
    existingProduct = null;
  }

  // updateToken(String? token, _items) {}

  // void showFavoritesOnly() {
  //   _showFavoritesOnly = true;
  //   notifyListeners();
  // }

  // void showAll() {
  //   _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  //   notifyListeners();
  // }
}
```

Structure of my firebase database:

[image]

Comment: There might be somewhere in the code that is probably rebuilding the UI resulting in block given below to not work correctly.

 leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoriteStatus(authData.token!, authData.userId);
              },
            ),
          ),

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? is it only the icon that is showing the wrong icon? or is it not fetching the right data? if you do debugPrint(isFavorite.toString()) is it true or false?

Comment: Could be in the fetching. Because as I have said in my Firebase, it is set as 'true' so it should be a shaded heart (indicates that a product is marked as favorite) instead of a bordered heart icon.  This line -> product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border, <- I think is correct in the product_item.dart.

Comment: in your products_provider try changing the fetch of "isFavorite" to this: isFavorite: favoriteData == null
              ? false
              : favoriteData[prodId] as bool? ?? false,

Comment: getting this error: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool?' in type cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is that I validated first the value of 'favoriteData' before passing it to 'isFavorite'. I am still new to having null pointer exception or null safety checks.

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProduct() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      if (extractedData == null) {
        return;
      }
      url = Uri.parse(
          'https://shopapp-bd154-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken');
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        var isFavorite = false;
        if (favoriteData != null && favoriteData[prodId] != null) {
          isFavorite = favoriteData[prodId]['isFavorite'] is bool &&
              favoriteData[prodId]['isFavorite'];
        }
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'] ?? '',
          description: prodData['description'] ?? '',
          price: prodData['price'] ?? 0.0,
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'] ?? '',
          isFavorite: isFavorite,

        ));
      });
      print(json.decode(favoriteResponse.body));
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```